# Where does CakePHP "i18n extract" get the file prefix from?

Tags: cakephp

We're in the process of switching from an Assembla to a GitHub repository for our CakePHP project. Currently, the output from "cake i18n extract" looks like this:

```
   ...
   #: http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/our_project_name/trunk/app/controllers   
   /wall_controller.php:333
   msgid ""
   "some error message"
   msgstr ""
   ...
```

Where does the http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/our_project_name/trunk prefix come from? (I assume it's set in a configuration file somewhere, but I couldn't find it by doing a grep for "assembla" in app/config, or even from the root.) I'd like to know so that I can change the prefix to point to the GitHub repository instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not from CakePHP

The extract task puts [relative path references](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php#L552-L558) in po files when they are extracted. A pot file generated by cake will look like this:

```
-> Console/cake i18n extract
...
-> cat Locale/cake.pot
# LANGUAGE translation of CakePHP Application
# Copyright YEAR NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-02-19 15:12+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM+ZZZZ\n"
"Last-Translator: NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"

#: View/Errors/error400.ctp:21
#: View/Errors/error500.ctp:21
msgid "Error"
msgstr ""

#: View/Errors/error400.ctp:23
msgid "The requested address %s was not found on this server."
msgstr ""

#: View/Errors/error500.ctp:22
msgid "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
msgstr ""
```

It's possible that assembla modifies these references when viewing online to point at their hosted location, or a previous developer changed the references in po files (note that the extract task doesn't generate po files, only pot files) for convenience.

If you're still seeing these assembla references in your pot files - check that the extract task in the Cake folder hasn't been modified, and that there is no app/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php file which would override the core task at run time.

Comment: I just redid the command and found that indeed the prefix is present in the raw output from the "cake i18n extract" command, so I'm not sure how to reconcile this with your answer. Perhaps our versions or our configurations are different. My cake/VERSION.txt file says 1.2.6.

Comment: [1.2.6](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/be7ddfb972a1fc508c3e4b0d8c78494923bc20e2) was released on 30 jan 2010 - that's eons old, would be a good idea to update to a more recent version. If you stick to that version check the source for [the version you're using](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.2.6/cake/console/libs/tasks/extract.php) - either it's been modified, or the file extract.php is in your app overriding it. The core extract task only uses file paths, not urls - it cannot be responsible for what you describe in the question AFAIK.

Comment: You're right -- someone modified the code in extract.php to add that prefix. (When I did the grep for "assembla", I should have redirected stderr to /dev/null, because I lost the one hit in extract.php among all the "Permission denied" noise about directories.) If you modify your answer above to include the possibility that you mentioned in your subsequent comment (that is, that extract.php was modified), I'll choose your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sure though the source having been modified is the kind of caveat that applies to any question about using a framework/library; After all the question is about using cake, not using "our code that long ago used to be cake".